# Use vim to convert markdown headings to org headings

Tags: vim, replace, substitution, string-substitution

Use vim to convert a file of markdown headings to org heading.

For example, change this:

```
# heading one
body
##heading two
### heading three
body
```

to this:

```
* heading one
body
**heading two
****** heading six
```

Only a continues sequence of '#' starting at column 0 should be substituted with an equal number of '*'.

This substitutes only the first '#' with '*':

```
%s/^[#]/*/c
```

But there can be up to six '#' to substitute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sub-string expression

```
%s/^#\+/\=repeat('*', len(submatch(0)))/
```

- match whole of `#` leading a line
- return repeated `*` numbered length of matched string

`submatch(0)` mean whole part of matched string